# Show that every recursively enumerable set is accepted by a Turing machine with only two non accepting states and one accepting state.

Tags: automata, turing-machines

A recursively enumerable set is a set where you can write a program that will output each element in the set: E1, E2, E3... it's okay if this program never stops.
For more info look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920074/what-are-recursively-enumerable-sets

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: It is accepted by *some* Turing machine $M$, and your machine can store the state of $M$ on an auxiliary tape, and simulate what $M$ would do.